# Windows Server 2003 -- Assign IP address to different programs

Tags: windows

I have a server with windows 2003 server OS installed. Got 2 NICs and 2 IPs on this computer. What I need to do is Program A uses internet connection on IP 1, and program B on IP 2.

Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

When a program opens a socket it has to specify on which interface (which IP address) it wants to bind to. Most programs do not even bother to write code to let a user chose which interface the software should bind on.

i don't believe there is any option anywhere in any version of Windows to allow you to customize, or override, that socket-open behavior.

---

i wish it could. i would love for µTorrent to operate on its own address; so i could easily shape it.